# Opencart 2 add to cart via 'model'

Tags: opencart

Is there a easy way to add a product to the cart by knowing the 'model' ID?
On the normal way it will added with product_id.

What function I do have to change for that?

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: find a way to map the model id to the product id

Comment: both of the modal id and the product id are in the same table, so you are just one step away from the normal workflow, the functions you need to change depends on what pages you want to change, basically avoid changing the function and find a way to map the model id to the product id first

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So actually than I need to find the function which is adding the item via product_id, copy it and write it for model id. Have you got an idea which file? contoller?

Comment: the client side version will be on "catalog\view\javascript\common.js", the name differs between version, before it was `addToCart` now it's an attribute `add` inside the cart object, following the AJAX request on the client side version you can find that the server side version is residing in `ControllerCheckoutCart` @ `add`, following this you can find there there is a method in `add` in the session cart helper object

Comment: Thx a lot Abdo Adel :) Will try it out tomorrow

Comment: Well, easy said, I am to stupid for that. I would like to post the code I used, but its too long